# How can (this specific) awk command be used in make with the result saved to a variable?

Tags: escaping, makefile, awk

I have tried two methods. A) using make's shell function and B) setting an environment variable. Both methods encounter trouble with escaping.

Roughly, the command I am trying to run in a makefile is

```
awk '{if ( $0 !~ /^#/ ) print $2 }' data.dat | tail -1
```

I want to store that value to a variable for later use. It's the exclamation mark that is causing the trouble. I have tried various methods of escaping it to no avail.

EDIT: After trying the suggestions below, it appears that the problem is more fundamental than just the exclamation mark. A new smaller test case is
something just like

```
 awk '{ print $2 }' data.dat | tail -1
```

where I'm now assuming the file doesn't have comments. The culprits are now the apostrophes or that I'm using a UNIX pipe within make.

EDIT 2: Half solution... I was forgetting to use $$ for a $ within make. Hopefully this allows me to post a solution.

EDIT 3: It appears the way parentheses are parsed in make during the definition of make variables, disallows the use commands called by the shell function which used them. Basically this means that gawk one-liners cannot really be used from make if one wants to store the results.

Comment: What shell does `make` use for these kinds of commands?

Comment: @bdesham The sh by default, even though it can be configured

Comment: I don’t know a lot about `sh` syntax, but have you tried enclosing the awk script in double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: I tried doubled quotes at one point and I assuming I did it correct, it didn't work. (sh is correct)

Comment: It will simplify things greatly if you include a bare-bones make file that exhibits your problem. (How are you trying to store the value of the variable?). And include details about OS, shell version, make version. Good luck!

Comment: I know that is often the case, shelter, but in this case I do not see that it's necessary. This is a specific question of how to use make, not a problem of reproducing a bug. In fact, by posting a specific implementation, I am biasing the answer towards a particular type of solution, which may cause others to be overlooked. Any makefile that successfully runs the first-posted command and stores the output for later use is an acceptable solution. The result I'm aiming for should be as OS agnostic as possible and make uses sh by default so that's answered by default.

Comment: Would you be willing to store the output in a file?

Comment: @Beta: I was trying to avoid that because the extra files make a work flow more complicated to understand. I've currently given up on the makefile-along approach and have used bash scripts to do what I wanted to do from make. So, yes, I did ended up using another file; but if I'm going to do that, it's better to use a shell script instead of a file generated from make as output.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t exactly answer your question, but I think you could bypass awk with

```
grep -v "^#" | cut -f 2 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: By trying this, I discovered that the problem is at a deeper level than the exclamation mark. I updated the question. Using grep is good idea. I'll have to figure out if it's more efficient or not than the awk alone solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your reg-exp to move where the negation takes place, i.e.

```
awk '{if ( $0 ~ /^[^#]/ ) print $2 }' data.dat | tail -1
       # -----^^^^^^^^
```

which says match any $0 (line) where the first char is NOT the '#' char.

You may be running into other issues because you're using make.

If this doesn't solve your problem, edit your post with your OS version, your `$SHELL` value, the version if possible, and `gmake` or `make` rules. ALSO copy/paste the relevant error messages you're getting.

I hope this helps.

Comment: After trying several variations on bdesham's post, the exclamation point isn't the hard part of the question. A new minimal test case is merely something of the form:   awk '{ print $2 }' data.dat | tail -1

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I miss the scope where within the Makefile you are trying to set a variable. As you already have noticed, you are facing several problems.

When thinking of *make(1)* and how it handles variables you should think of it as a macro processor (in contrast to expect shell-like behaviour). For example the following Makefile

```
A = HEHE
B = HOHO
C = $A $B
A = HAHA

default:
        echo $C
```

produces the output "HAHA HOHO" whereas a shell-programmer wold expect "HEHE HOHO". So "later" is a somewhat misleading term with Makefiles.

Of course you can invoke shell commands within rules, but be warned: Each line in a rule is executed within it's own shell process, so even if you set a (Shell-) variable, it's lost with the next command line.

My recomendations:

- If you really need to store intermediate values, use temporary files.
- If you need to code complex shell commands, place them in a seperate script file

Of course one may use line continuation (\ at end of line) and extended use of escape-quotes to code complex shell constructs within a Makefile and lot of people do so - but this is not what make(1) was designed for - The resulting scripts are horrible to read and searching for errors or misbehaviours is a tedious task.